# Update column with concat of second column and a variable

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update column values (say column2) with concatenation of two string variables (say str1 & str2) with another column (say column1). Final value which I need in column2 is str1 as prefix and str2 as suffix to column1 value.

One way which can be done is with a dummy third column and a total of 4 update queries.

```
update table set column3 = str1;
update table set column2 = concat(column3, column1);
update table set column3 = str2;
update table set column2 = concat(column2, column3);
```

But I want to reduce that to a single update without using a dummy column, like below -

```
update table set column2 = concat($str1, column1, $str2);
```

I need help in the concat part of the above query.

Comment: Did you try it? `CONCAT()` will accept as many params as needed.  `UPDATE tbl SET col2 = CONCAT('str1', col1, 'str2');`

Comment: @Michael I need to use a variable instead of a static string. Values for $str1 and $str2 are not same every time I run this update.

Comment: Did you try it? you can add variables to your SQL string in PHP

Comment: @Prashanth then use variables: `UPDATE tbl SET col2 = CONCAT('$str1', col1, '$str2');` Just be sure to escape them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason this not to work:

```
$prefix = mysql_realescape_string($str1);
$suffix = mysql_realescape_string($str2);
$sql = "UPDATE table SET cloumn2 = CONCAT('$prefix', column1, '$suffix')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP, there is your solution:

```
$query="update table set column2 = concat('$str1', column1, '$str2');";
```

You were actually very close to solution.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my other comment, str 1 & 2 are dynamic values. Every time I run this update the str values are different.

Comment: They are dynamic... Asuming you have them in PHP variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

`$sql = "UPDATE table SET column2 = CONCAT_WS('-', '$str1', column1, '$str2');";`

The first argument for CONCAT_WS is the string character you'd like to concatenate with.